# What is the maximum input length of MD5 function?

Tags: security, hash, cryptography

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Maximum length for MD5 input/output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394503/maximum-length-for-md5-input-output)

I know that MD5 function produces a maximum length of 32 bytes, but what about its maximum input?

Comment: MD5 always outputs 128 bits or 16 bytes, not 32 bytes. If you use a hexadecimal representation of 16 bytes, you get 32 characters. But that encoding unrelated to MD5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no maximum input length.