# Objective-C Implicit conversion loses integer precision (size_t to CC_Long)

Tags: objective-c, macos

I have a function that's generating a sha256 encryption of a string,

Here's the function:

```
    -(NSString*)sha256HashFor:(NSString*)input
{
    const char* str = [input UTF8String];
    unsigned char result[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_SHA256(str, strlen(str), result);

    NSMutableString *ret = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH*2];
    for(int i = 0; i<CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        [ret appendFormat:@"%02x",result[i]];
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Now this line right here `CC_SHA256(str, strlen(str), result);` is what's producing this warning (the warning is for the strlen(str) variable).

```
Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'CC_LONG' (aka 'unsigned int')
```

I'm guessing I just need to convert the strlen(str) to a CC_Long, but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: `(CC_LONG)strlen(str)`

Comment: What kind of compiler/toolchain and settings are you using? This seems like something overly pedantic.

Comment: By the way, why would this be tagged osx or automatic-ref-counting... exactly zero of either of these is in the question.

Comment: @mah Just like when iOS programming questions are tagged with `xcode` - *why?* Would it really matter if OP used Eclipse instead? Whatever...

Answer (score 56, accepted):

1. Presumably that's not an error but a warning.
2. "I just need to convert the strlen(str) to a CC_Long, but I have no idea how to do that." - explicit type conversion (type casting): `(CC_LONG)strlen(str)`, but I don't think you really need this.

Comment: it is a warning indeed... warning you that in theory the size_t could be bigger than the CC_Long ... add a cast to say: yes  I know and it is okay

Comment: @Daij-Djan Yep, I find it either unlikely or potentially screwed up if a string is more than 4GB long (on OS X `int` is 4 bytes wide).

Comment: It was just was just a warning, however my app is breaking on this line every time I run it.

Comment: I actually fixed it, turned out even though it was breaking on that line, it was from a different reason. However, this answer still answered the original question. Got rid of that warning :D

Comment: Thanks for a quick around solution. it worked for me. Thnk u very much

Answer (score 3):

This code will not show any warning and works perfectly.

```
- (NSString*) sha256 {
    const char * pointer = [self UTF8String];
    unsigned char result[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_SHA256(pointer, (CC_LONG)strlen(pointer), result);

    NSMutableString *ret = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH*2];
    for(int i = 0; i<CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        [ret appendFormat:@"%02x",result[i]];
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Speaking from the iOS perspective, the fact that CC_LONG (a.k.a. uint32_t) and size_t (unsigned long) are incompatible sizes can be a security/stability concern in some applications, especially when dealing with reusable library functions.

An MD5 hash is a 128 bit hash of a potentially unlimited length message, so there is a good reason for this warning.  If you truncate a length greater than 2^32, you will come up with an incorrect hash.

Your code should logically decide on how large of a string it can support.  In this case using CC_MD5, it would have to be 2^32 bytes.

[Maximum length for MD5 input/output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394503/maximum-length-for-md5-input-output)