# How to convert/use CC_SHA1 method so that it can be used in a 64 bit system

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, 64-bit

I am converting my app to work on a 64 bit system and I got stuck on trying to properly use a built in `CC_SHA1` method.

I get the warning:

> **Implicit conversion loses integer precision: ‘NSUInteger’ (aka ‘unsigned long’) to ‘CC_LONG’ (aka ‘unsigned int’)**

when trying to pass: `data.length` in `CC_SHA1` method.

`data.length` is `NSUInteger`

`CC_SHA1` method definition is:

```
extern unsigned char *CC_SHA1(const void *data, CC_LONG len, unsigned char *md)
```

where `CC_LONG` is a 32 bit `unsigned integer`.

How can I change it to use  `CC_LONG64` instead?

```
typedef uint64_t CC_LONG64;
```

This is the conversion method where I get the above warning:

```
+(NSString*)sha1:(NSString*)input
{
    const char *cstr = [input cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cstr length:input.length];

    uint8_t digest[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    CC_SHA1(data.bytes, data.length, digest);

    NSMutableString* output = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];

    for(NSInteger i = 0; i < CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
        [output appendFormat:@"%02x", digest[i]];

    return output;

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C Implicit conversion loses integer precision (size\_t to CC\_Long)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17013838/objective-c-implicit-conversion-loses-integer-precision-size-t-to-cc-long)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming that the data length is less than `2^32`, you can add 
an explicit cast without losing any information.
This should remove the warning:

```
CC_SHA1(data.bytes, (CC_LONG)data.length, digest);
```