# Mysql Binary data type

Tags: mysql, types, binary

So my binary is:
0011010101100100001101000011000100110100001100000011001001100001011000100110001100110100011000100011001001100001001101110011011001100010001110010011011100110001001110010110010000111001001100010011000100110000001100010011011101100011001101010011100100110010

Md5:
5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592

Password:
hello

I know the datatype is BINARY in mysql but what size do i need to make it? what do i fill in for the x?

```
BINARY(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394503/maximum-length-for-md5-input-output), you can predict the size of a md5.

If you don't want to, it seems like [VARBINARY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/binary-varbinary.html) type is what you're looking for.

Comment: According to this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5 and what you linked me to, you can predict the size of a md5 hash. an md5 hash is always a 32 character string. and no, i want to store my Binary as a Binary in MYSQL.

Comment: Ok I really missunderstood your question. Sorry about that, Richard Grant has the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MANUAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-varbinary.html):

```
[...] the length for BINARY and VARBINARY is a length in bytes rather than in characters.
```